# Probability that the minimum of two uniform variables is greater than the maximum of two uniform variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose I have two random variables $A = \min(X_1, Y_1)$ and $B = \max(X_2, Y_2)$ where $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ are uniform and **independent** on some interval, say $[0, 1]$. What is $p(B < A)$?

I've worked out the basic step that $f_A(a) = 2-2a$ and $f_B(b) = 2b$, but I'm struggling with using this to determine the probability I'm interested in.

Comment: Now that you've worked out the probability density functions of $A$ and $B$, you can use the following integral: $$\mathbb{P}(B < A) = \int_0^1{f_A(a) \mathbb{P}(B < a)\,\mathrm{d}a} = \int_0^1{f_A(a) \int_0^a{f_B(b)\,\mathrm{d}b}\,\mathrm{d}a}\,\text{.}$$ This is really a double integral over the set $\Omega := \{(a, b) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \mid b < a\}$: $$\iint_\Omega{f_A(a)f_B(b) \,\mathrm{d}a \,\mathrm{d}b}\,\text{.}$$

Comment: It’s literally impossible to have the condition you wrote, so the probability is $0$

Comment: @neil Can you please clarify whether the $A,B$ in your question are calculated from *the same values* of $X$ and $Y$, or from *distinct* random values drawn from the same distribution.

Comment: Almost every thing on this page is wrong if there is no extra assumption on $X$ and $Y$ . ARE THEY INDEPENDENT?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter the distribution of $X_1, X_2, Y_1, Y_2$ as long as they are i.i.d. and the probability of "draws" is zero. Also, you don't need calculus. The only thing that matters is their relative order; there are $4! = 24$ possible and equally likely orderings. Out of them, your condition is true when:

$$
X_1 > Y_1 > X_2 > Y_2, 
$$
$$
X_1 > Y_1 > Y_2 > X_2, 
$$
$$
Y_1 > X_1 > X_2 > Y_2, 
$$
$$
Y_1 > X_1 > Y_2 > X_2, 
$$

So we have that $P(B < A ) = \frac{4}{24} = \frac{1}{6}$.

Even simpler: There is a probability of $\frac{1}{2}$ that the biggest value comes from $A$. If so, there is a probability of $\frac{1}{3}$ that the second biggest comes also from $A$.

Answer (score 2):

Rounding my earlier comment into an answer, we can use the independence of $A$ and $B$ to find that the probability density function $f_{AB}(a,b) = f_A(a) f_B(b)$. Now, we want to find the total probability over the subset of the possibility space $\Omega$ such that $B < A$.

Defining the half-space we're interested in as $H := \{(a, b) \in [0,1] \times [0,1] \mid b < a\}$, we have
$$\mathbb{P}(B < A) = \iint_H{f_A(a)f_B(b) \,\mathrm{d}a \,\mathrm{d}b}\,\text{.}$$

Now, by Fubini's theorem, we can expand this double integral into an integrated integral:
$$\mathbb{P}(B < A) = \int_0^1{f_A(a) \int_0^a{f_B(b)\,\mathrm{d}b}\,\mathrm{d}a}\,\text{.}$$

Making the necessary substitutions,
$$\begin{aligned}\mathbb{P}(B < A) &= \int_0^1{(2 - 2a) \int_0^a{2b\,\mathrm{d}b}\,\mathrm{d}a}\\
&=\int_0^1{2a^2 - 2a^3 \,\mathrm{d}a}\\
&=\left[ \frac{2}{3}a^3 - \frac{1}{2}a^4\right]_{x = 0}^1 = \frac{1}{6}\,\text{.}\end{aligned}$$

ETA: This is of course, all assuming that the variables $A$ and $B$ *are* independent. If $A$ and $B$ are not calculated using independent random variables $X_A, Y_A, X_B, Y_B$, but instead calculated using the same random variables, then obviously the maximum of two variables cannot be greater than their minimum, so $\mathbb{P}(B < A) = 0$, as I think A rural reader was saying.

Comment: how are A and B independent? It is always the case that $\max(X,Y) \geq \min(X,Y)$, so how are they independent?

Comment: @AspiringMat I was assuming that the $X$ and $Y$ in each were distinct bound variables used in defining $A$ and $B$, reused for convenience. If this is the case we may If instead write $A = \min(X,Y)$, $B = \max(Z,W)$, where $X,Y,Z,W$ are uniformly distributed on $[0,1]$. If they are free variables of course it is true that $\max(X,Y) \geq \min(X,Y)$. Like how one may write $\min\{x \mid x \in [1,2]\} > \max\{x \mid X \in [-2, -1]\}$.

Comment: Okay, I get what you mean. Although I’d assume with the way the question is currently written that they’re the same variables.

Comment: The question is simply wrong. OP doesn't say if $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: Doesn't this overcomplicate things? I guess that it's just the relative order that matters and you can simply enumerate the favourable cases.